# Split string on embedded character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a master table that I am inserting data into from an import temp table. The data doesnt require alot of massaging, but one column that does is one that deals with dimensions. The dimensions I record is length, width and height. They are three separate columns, varchar(10) in each.

The import table has these combined into one column, delimited by an "x", so LxWxH.

Ultimately I am writing this transformation into an executable stored procedure, but I'm getting stuck on this split. Can someone give me a hand on how to code this?

The template of my insert is:
Assuming master table is ID (int), Length varchar(10), width varchar(10), height varchar(10)
Assuming import table is ID (int), Dims varchar(50)

Data looks like (from import) :

```
1   1.2x3.5x9.5
2   2.4x3.5x8.5
etc etc
```

The code:

```
insert into [mastertable]
id, length, width, height
select
from [importtable]
```

Any help is appreciated! The SQL Server version is 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT dbo.mastertable (id, length, width, height)
SELECT 
  ID, 
  L, 
  W = SUBSTRING(R, 1, CHARINDEX('x', r)-1),
  H = SUBSTRING(R, LEN(R)-CHARINDEX('x', REVERSE(r))+2, 255)
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, LWH, 
    L = SUBSTRING(LWH, 1, CHARINDEX('x', LWH)-1),
    r = SUBSTRING(LWH, CHARINDEX('x', LWH)+1, 255)
  FROM dbo.importtable
) AS x;
```

Comment: Yeesh.. that was a mouthful, but it definitely worked. Thanks!

Comment: @optionsix yeah I never claimed it was pretty. There are probably 30 or 40 ways to do it, all of which have varying levels or readability/prettiness.